# enable-spfeature publishingsite causes all sharepoint pages to say "access denied"

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

We're trying to enable the SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure on a SharePoint 2013 site, but as soon as we run `enable-spfeature publishingsite -url http://companyweb` all http://companyweb pages return Access Denied, even for administrators. Disabling the feature restores access.

This particular site was upgraded from SharePoint 3.0 AND migrated to a new domain, so I'm guessing something went haywire there, but the rest of the site works fine and I'm struggling to find what else might be causing this issue.

I've already checked the site is running as the same account as the Central Administration App Pool as per https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9a562b85-c84d-47db-9060-4c90fef76013/acess-denied-error-when-activating-office-sharepoint-server-publishing-infrastructure?forum=sharepointadminlegacy

Any other ideas?